# Populating a table through jquery through select option, each time option is clicked it increments the table by one

Tags: jquery

Basically I am having an issue with populating a table through jQuery on click of a select option.

I have used a switch statement to switch the content between each option. I can populate the table through jQuery however the problem exists when I populate a table through and select an option more than once, each time the option is selected the table is incrementing by 1.

I have included a `js fiddle`, hope this make sense: http://jsfiddle.net/thesarahjay/yGgjF/

Thanks,

Melissa

Comment: Because you are not clearing the containers of the tables!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `empty` your table and container each time, else you just keep appending. Add this to both switch statements:

```
$('table').empty(); //clear table
$("#one").empty(); //clear div
```

Aaaand a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yGgjF/3/

Comment: Works great, thanks a bunch! I now understand where I was going wrong. Thanks again

Comment: @MelissaBoyle -- Be sure to mark an answer if the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

You need to clear the container each time

```
handleNewSelection = function () {
    $("#one,#two,#three").html(""); //you can use empty() too
   // Rest of code goes here....
}
```

**Fiddle Demo** `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/yGgjF/4/